# Loading asar file into Electron via Robot Framework / Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, electron

I have an Electron app packaged as an app.asar file. It runs fine when opened with Electron, and I need to find a way to run tests on it through Robot Framework.

The problem is that while I can start the Electron app through Robot, I cannot find a way to pass it the app.asar file. And both the app and Electron are located in entirely different locations.

Based on the [only very succinct source I could find mentioning both Electron and Robot Framework](http://spage.fi/electron), I made the following:

*vars.py :*

```
binary_location = {"chromeOptions": {"binary": "C:/path/to/electron/electron.exe"}}
```

*ElectronTest.txt*

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           OperatingSystem
Variables         vars.py

*** Variables ***
${Delay}          1s
${executor}       http://localhost:9515

*** Test Cases ***
Foo
    Set Selenium Speed    ${Delay}
    Create Webdriver    Remote    desired_capabilities=${binary_location}    command_executor=${executor}
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    css=.workspace
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers

*** Keywords ***

Set Environment Variable
    webdriver.chrome.driver    ./chromedriver.exe
```

This starts Electron but gives me the following error:

> The app provided is not a valid electron app, please read the docs on
>   how to write one:  https://github.com/atom/electron/tree/master/docs
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\path\to\ElectronTest:data'

Which makes sense, considering I didn't actually pass the app, even though I don't know why it is looking for an app in the Robot Framework folder

I also tried replacing the executor with the path to my app, as such:

```
${executor}      file://C:/path/to/my/app/dist/app.asar
```

In that case, I get the following error from Robot Framework:

> URLError: urlopen error [Error 3] The system cannot find the path
>   specified:
>   u'path\to\my\app\dist\app.asar\session'

No idea why it would try to reach "app.asar\session".

I'm guessing I'm missing a parameter somewhere, but no matter how much I search and try, I cannot find any way to solve this.

**Is there any way to pass a .asar file to Electron through Robot Framework?**

Comment: i think `chromeOptions` should be `goog:chromeOptions`. Were you ever able to figure this problem out?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions you linked to assume that you've packaged your electron app into a .exe. It's not clear if you did that first step or not, but the error message implies that you did not ("The app provided is not a valid electron app").

If you didn't, you might want to read [Application Distribution][1] in the electron docs. When you are done, you will have created a custom .exe that includes your asar file and whatever other files. It is the path to *this* .exe and not the `electron.exe` that you downloaded that you must start with robot.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the difference, but I don't really have the freedom to repackage the app. We are specifically working with this setup (electron.exe + app.asar), and I'm supposed to work within those bounds :/